# nm get undefined symbols for whole archive, not separate object files

Tags: c++, c, gcc, static-libraries

I have two files:

`foo.c`: `int foo() { extern int bar(); return bar(); }`

`bar.c`: `int bar() { extern int missing(); return missing() + 42; }`

I compile them and and compose into `.a` static lib:

```
$ gcc -c foo.c bar.c
$ ar rcs libfoobar.a foo.o bar.o
```

I want to find which symbols are missing (undefined) from whole archive. But I still get `bar` as undefined, while it exists in `foo.o`:

```
$ nm -u libfoobar.a
foo.o:
    U bar
bar.o:
    U missing
```

How can I omit `bar` from output and show only `missing`?

Comment: I added another script to do the task you want. Does it help you?

Comment: You get `bar` as undefined in `foo.o`, and `missing` as undefined in `bar.o`, both of which are correct. Unclear what you're asking for. `nm` isn't a linker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link the whole archive into a single object file and check that:

```
ar -x libfoo.a      # unpack libfoo.a
ld -r -o tmp.o *.o  # link all objects into tmp.o
nm -u tmp.o         # find undefined symbols in tmp.o
rm *.o              # remove tmp.o as well as the contents of libfoo.a
```

This should give the desired result as the linker resolves all symbols it can find in the partial link requested by `-r`.

Note that the current working directory should not contain any object files for best results.

You can use the following script for more consistent results:

```
# use: script libfoo.a
tmp=${TEMPDIR:-/tmp}/undefsyms.$$
mkdir $tmp
cp $1 $tmp/lib.a
cd $tmp
ar -x lib.a
ld -r -o $$.o *.o
nm -u $$.o
rm *
cd ..
rmdir $tmp
```

If you feel uncomfortable unpacking and linking the library for this purpose, use this script which uses command line utilities to compute the information you need using the `join` utility:

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
    echo Usage: $0 library.a
    exit 1
fi

lib=$1

postproc() { cut -w -f 2-3 | sort -u; }
allsyms() { nm -g -P -A $lib | postproc; }
undefsyms() { nm -g -P -A -u $lib | postproc; }
defsyms() { allsyms | grep -v 'U$'; }

comm -2 -3 <(undefsyms | cut -w -f 1) <(defsyms | cut -w -f 1)
```

Comment: This script is very useful, when you need to map out link-time dependencies, and want to avoid the CPU/memory cost of performing a trial link, for example when surveying how dependencies have evolved over the history of a (large) project.

I had to replace `cut -w` with `cut -d " "`

Answer (score 2):

The archival tool just creates ... well, an archive. It's not a linker. References are resolved by your linker, and this process will find `foo.o`'s reference to `bar` to be resolved in `bar.o`. The archiver can't do that, and `nm` won't do it either - it's just running itself over each object inside the archive, independently.

Comment: I undestand that `ar` is just and archiver, but I hoped `nm` or some other tool can "match" defined and undefined symbols in whole archive.

Comment: @flapenguin, nope. ar archive is not much different from zip archive. It is merely a collection of .o files (and a symbol table). And nm **never** matches anything. It works with a single file and basically prints object file structure.